# Is there a way for R to read info from an outlook email when it comes in?

Tags: r

Unfortunately I don’t have any code for this question since I don’t know how to code it.

Is there a way for R to grab info from a new outlook email?

Example, I get the same type of email multiple times a day. When it comes in I want to parse through it for info that I’ll compare to a data set to potentially update the data set and send another email out. Also would there be a way to have this happen without me running the script each time?

TL;DR: what I want to do

1. I receive an outlook email.
2. R script imports the information in that email (primary thing I don’t know how to do), it’s just the text of the email.
3. Script does data validation
4. R script sends out an email

BONUS: This is all somehow automated and I don’t have to run the script each time the email comes in.

Answer (score 1):

My [Microsoft365R](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Microsoft365R) package is an interface to Microsoft 365, including Outlook. You can send and read emails from R, in either text or HTML format. It also supports using blastula to compose emails in Markdown.

Comment: Thank you for this, I’m reading through the documentation, but it’s a lot of info. Is there a tutorial or example anywhere on reading the text of an email into R for analysis? The text of the email I get will have info like customer name and zip code, and I need to add that info to a data set.

Comment: The body of the email is in the `properties$body` component. It'll be a character string, most likely HTML-formatted text. You can use the xml2 or rvest packages to scrape it

Comment: Which function grabs the text of the email?

Comment: See `?ms_outlook_email`

Comment: Im still a bit confused as ive been going through this. Lets say i just received an email and i want to pull the text of that email i received into R. I use ```ms_outlook_email```?